# jQuery link for bootstrap

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I have noticed that the bootstrap provides a jQuery link that you can use to run the JavaScript files. What I would like to know is if it matters what jQuery link you use.

Currently, the code provided by the bootstrap site is:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Would it hurt if I used these links below to replace the above link:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: What is also important is that you must trust the source your choose,  because you download routines and execute them (or you do this on the final user machine). If the source contains modified routines, then strange things may happen.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It will not create any issue as `jQuery library` version is same. as per your link both files version is same that means files is same but loads from different server.

Main thing is you need to use `jQuery library` suggested by `bootstrap`

> jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) .

you can download that files to your local project folder and use in project it will work fine.

[jQuery Migrate Plugin](https://jquery.com/download/#jquery-migrate-plugin)

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js"></script>
```

> jQuery Migrate Plugin simplify the transition from older versions of
>   jQuery. The plugin restores deprecated features and behaviors so that
>   older code will still run properly on jQuery 1.9 and later.

Answer (score 4):

No. It will be not. Because the links which you have mentioned will have the same jquery files and those links are nothing but different **[CDNs](http://www.webopedia.com/TERM/C/CDN.html)**  that deliver webpages and other Web content to a user based on the geographic locations of the user, the origin of the webpage and a content delivery server.

As per the mentioned link **this service is effective in speeding the delivery of content of websites with high traffic and websites that have global reach. The closer the CDN server is to the user geographically, the faster the content will be delivered to the user.**

Answer (score 4):

These two file are exactly the same therefore you should not see any difference.